# How to get better performance from LINQ-to-SQL large dataset update

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I have a c# console application that is updating a database with about 320,000 records. Basically it is encrypting a password in each record in a loop, then calling DatabaseContext.SubmitChanges(). The "UPDATE" part of the code takes about 20 seconds. I had to CTRL-C the app because it's taking over 15 minutes to do the "SubmitChanges" part: this is part of a time-sensitive system that should not be down for more than a couple minutes.
I ran SQL Profiler and I'm seeing queries like this for each update:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[PointRecord]
SET [PtPassword] = @p19
WHERE ([ID] = @p0) AND ([PtLocation] = @p1) AND ([PtIPAddress] = @p2) AND ([PtPort] = @p3) AND ([PtUsername] = @p4) AND ([PtPassword] = @p5) AND ([PtGWParam1] = @p6) AND ([PtGWParam2] = @p7) AND ([PtGWParam3] = @p8) AND ([PtGWParam4] = @p9) AND ([PtTag] = @p10) AND ([PtCapture] = @p11) AND ([PtGroup] = @p12) AND ([PtNumSuccess] = @p13) AND ([PtNumFailure] = @p14) AND ([PtControllerType] = @p15) AND ([PtControllerVersion] = @p16) AND ([PtAssocXMLGroupID] = @p17) AND ([PtErrorType] IS NULL) AND ([PtPollInterval] = @p18)',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 nvarchar(4000),@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 nvarchar(4000),@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 int,@p12 nvarchar(4000),@p13 int,@p14 int,@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 nvarchar(4000),@p17 int,@p18 int,@p19 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=296987,@p1=N'1234 Anytown USA',@p2=N'10.16.31.20',@p3=N'80',@p4=N'username1',@p5=N'password1',@p6=N'loadmon.htm?PARM2=21',@p7=N'>Operating Mode',@p8=N'',@p9=N'',@p10=N'1234 Anytown USA\HLTH SERVICE LTS\Operating Modeloadmon',@p11=0,@p12=N'1234 Anytown USA',@p13=0,@p14=0,@p15=N'DeviceA',@p16=N'3.5.0.2019.0219',@p17=309,@p18=15,@p19=N'hk+MUoeVMG69pOB3DHYB8g=='
```

As you can see, the "WHERE" part is asking for EVERY SINGLE FIELD to match, when this is an indexed table, using unique primary key "ID". This is really time-consuming. Is there any way to get this to only use "WHERE ID=[value]"?

Comment: [ExecuteQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery?view=netframework-4.8) may help you make update requests that bypass the stored procedure.

Comment: I concur.  Write your own query for this.  You'll have better control, and significantly improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

I understand now that checking every field is a requirement of concurrency checking in EF. To bypass, methods outside of LINQ are required. 
I ended up using a variation of what Mr. Petrov and Mr. Harvey suggested, using ExecuteCommand since I am updating the database, not querying for data. 
Here is sample code, in case it can help others with a similar issue.
It uses LINQ to get the records to update and the record count for user feedback.
It uses ExecuteCommand to update the records. I am actually updating three tables (only one is shown in the sample below), hence the use of a transaction object.
The EncryptPassword method is not shown. It is what I use to update the records. You should replace that with whatever update logic suits your needs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DatabaseHelpers.Initialize();
    if (DatabaseHelpers.PasswordsEncrypted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DatabaseHelpers indicates that passwords are already encrypted. Exiting.");
        return;
    }

    // Note that the DatabaseHelpers.DbContext is in a helper library,
    //  it is a copy of the auto-generated EF 'DataClasses1DataContext'.
    //  It has already been opened using a generated connection string
    //  (part of DatabaseHelpers.Initialize()).
    //  I have altered some of the variable names to hide confidential information.
    try
    {
        // show user what's happening
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting passwords...");
        // flip switch on encryption methods
        DatabaseHelpers.PasswordsEncrypted = true;
        int recordCount = 0;

        // Note: Using LINQ to update the records causes an unacceptable delay because of the concurrency checking
        //  where the UPDATE statement (at SubmitChanges) checks EVERY field instead of just the ID
        //  and we don't care about that!
        // We have to set up an explicit transaction in order to use with context.ExecuteCommand statements
        //  start transaction - all or nothing
        DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.Transaction = DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();

        // update non-null and non-empty passwords in groups
        Console.Write("Updating RecordGroups");
        List<RecordGroup> recordGroups = (from p in DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.RecordGroups
                                    where p.RecordPassword != null && p.RecordPassword != string.Empty
                                    select p).ToList();
        recordCount = recordGroups.Count;
        foreach (RecordGroup rGroup in recordGroups)
        {
            // bypass LINQ-to-SQL
            DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE RecordGroup SET RecordPassword={0} WHERE ID={1}", DatabaseHelpers.EncryptPassword(rGroup.RecordPassword), rGroup.ID);
            Console.Write('.');
        }

        // show user what's happening
        Console.WriteLine("\nCommitting transaction...");
        DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.Transaction.Commit();

        // display results
        Console.WriteLine($"Updated {recordCount} RecordGroup passwords. Exiting.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nThere was an error executing the password encryption process: {ex}");
        DatabaseHelpers.DbContext.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```